# R Mosek using quadratic programming

Tags: r, optimization

I found the RMosek library to solve optimization problems. In my case, I will use quadratic optimization. This is the documentation about the quadratic optimization present on Rmosek: https://docs.mosek.com/9.0/rmosek/tutorial-qo-shared.html#

For example, I have this problem:

`min y1^2 + y2^2
 x1 + y1 - x2 - y2 > 0
 x1+x2=2`

I don't understand how to transform mine formulation as matrix formulation. I don't think the example on the documentation is very clear. Can someone help me?

Comment: Without experience, you might want to use something more high-level, like [cvxr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/CVXR/index.html)

Comment: ok! Thank you! I will check it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your variables are ordered as (x1,x2,y1,y2) i.e. x1 has index 1, and so on until y2 has index 4. Then your quadratic objective is specified with

```
prob$qobj$i <- c(3, 4)
prob$qobj$j <- c(3, 4)
prob$qobj$v <- c(2, 2)
```

and for the linear part you should use the matrix

```
1 -1 1 -1
1 1 0 0
```

and the bounds are

```
prob$bc <- rbind(blc=c(0,2), buc=c(Inf,2))
```

By the way if you really just want to minimize the norm of a vector you would be better off using the quadratic cone and conic optimization instead of formulating it as a quadratic term.

Comment: Thank you Michal! :) I will study the quadratic cone and conic optimization. :)

Comment: Can you also explain to me what is the difference between the object i and object j? 
The object v contain the exponents I think.

Comment: @TheAvenger v contains coefficients and (i,j) is are indexes. For example, if you had a quadratic term 10 * x9 * x7 (or, in symmetric form 0.5*(10*x9*x7+10*x7*x9)) then i=9, j=7, v=10 (only the lower-triangular part is specified). If you have 1*x5^2 (that is 0.5*(2*x5*x5)) then i=5, j=5, v=2.